# How can i prevent Unity from packaging an external resource-file on a build?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'd like to have a config jsonfile that i can edit in a compiled build. Right now, Unity packages my file together with other resources into one file, is there a way to prevent this for a file?

Comment: Don't include it in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

From the [unity docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.html):

> all assets in the "Resources" folders will be included in a build

If your config.json isn't in the Resources folder, then it will only be included in the build if it is loaded or otherwise used by a script object in the game.

If you need to access data in config.json but don't want the end-user to be able to modify the file, then consider serializing your config into a binary blob.

PS: please go back and accept some answers to your previous questions. We answerers need the karma!